# Text-shadow, different browsers/different effect

Tags: html, css

I've tinkered with text-shadow and achieved an effect I really like in safari, however it is rendered differently in ff & chrome. I'm very wet behind the ears but believed that text-shadow would work the same on most browsers as the prefixes (-moz, -webkit, ect) are no longer used for it. Thanks.

```
h1 { color:#a2d639; text-shadow:0 0 10px #fff,0 0 20px #fff,0 0 30px #66ff33,0 0 40px #66ff33,0 0 70px #ff00de,0 0 80px #66ff33,0 0 100px #ff00de,0 0 150px #ff00de;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same (and multiple other issues) concerning cross-browser compatibility. Unfortunately, the best current solution is to find a "happy medium" between the browsers. Be sure to check the results frequently if you're making a lot of changes.

If you haven't done so already, download the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, and Opera to test your pages. As far as I know, Safari, Chrome and Opera use the Webkit rendering engine, but there are still slight differences in how they are displayed.